# where file is saved in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf-generation, fpdf, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I want to use wkhtmltopdf  for html to pdf conversion. The program seems to work but I dont know where the target file is saved. Ideally it should be saved in programfiles-->wkhtmltopdf  folder.

Does anyone experience this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate the document, you choose where to save the file. Refer to their [usage wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage) for simple examples on how to use it. There is also a [manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) for the various options and detailed information on it. You can find different versions of the manual [here](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/).

Usage:

```
wkhtmltopdf [OPTIONS]... <input file> [More input files] <output file>
```

Examples:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com example.pdf
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com f:\example.pdf
```

If you choose the first example, the file will be saved in which ever directory you are currently located in.